# Cannot find -lbgi and ld returned 1 exit status error

Tags: c++, mingw, project, dev-c++, bgi

I am trying to draw lines in c++ graphics by using dev c++, here is the code

```
// C++ Implementation for drawing line 
#include <graphics.h> 

// driver code 
int main() 
{ 
    // gm is Graphics mode which is a computer display 
    // mode that generates image using pixels. 
    // DETECT is a macro defined in "graphics.h" header file 
    int gd = DETECT, gm; 

    // initgraph initializes the graphics system 
    // by loading a graphics driver from disk 
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, ""); 

    // line for x1, y1, x2, y2 
    line(150, 150, 450, 150); 

    // line for x1, y1, x2, y2 
    line(150, 200, 450, 200); 

    // line for x1, y1, x2, y2 
    line(150, 250, 450, 250); 

    getch(); 

    // closegraph function closes the graphics 
    // mode and deallocates all memory allocated 
    // by graphics system . 
    closegraph(); 
}
```

But following errors are showing again and again in compiling and I am not sure how to fix these.

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/libbgi.a when searching for -lbgi
C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../lib/libbgi.a when searching for -lbgi
C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../libbgi.a when searching for -lbgi
C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lbgi
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\Makefile.win:25: recipe for target 'Project1.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Project1.exe] Error 1
```

Error screenshot

[image]

I have tried including these in the project parameters linker tab

- -lbgi
- -lgdi32
- -lcomdlg32
- -luuid
- -loleaut32
- -lole32

Also, I have graphics.h library in devc++ folder. But not sure why this error keeps popping up. Kindly someone point out at my mistake.

Comment: Where is `libbgi.lib` installed on your environment? If you find it at a particular directory, you can instrument the linker to find it using the `-L <directory>` option.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't have libbgi.lib. I have libbgi.a in devcpp folder

Comment: @SabiqaRani but you have the message _skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/libbgi.a_. Is like you have lib for 64b but you are in 32b. In that case you need to get the libs for 32b or to compile for 64b rather than for 32b. Can you edit your question to put the full command to compile/link ?

Comment: @bruno how to compile for 64 bit? As I have 64b operating system, 64b DEVc++ and 64b lib file. Then why the project is compiling in 32b?

Comment: do you use option like `-m32` ?, if yes this is why you compile in 32b. ELse try using option `-m64`

Comment: I am compiling in devc++ by simply clicking the compiling button.

Comment: I do not use that tool but you certainly have (default)configuration you can change

Comment: There is no option like -m32 or -m64, it's just the simple compile button in devc++

Comment: try adding the option -m64 among compiler options, and force to recompile all

Comment: Ok I am going to try your instructions. wait

Comment: (crossing fingers ^^)

Comment: @bruno I have tried compiling it in 64b manually, but same result. :(

Comment: @SabiqaRani oh, you also have the message about "skipping incompatible" on the static lib (.a) ?

Comment: @bruno no. nothing is written about static lib

Comment: so what error do you have ?

Comment: @bruno I have edited the question and posted the screenshot of error. Kindly view it.

Comment: IIRC `graphics.h` is MS-DOS BGI !!! on windows there is `WinBGI` on Linux are some ports too... So if your BGI is really the MS-DOS version your compile/link target must be 16 bit MS-DOS !!! so no 32 nor 64 bit. If it is different BGI then the header file is most likely with different name like `WinBGI.h`.  Header `graphics.h` is common for many gfx libs not just BGI so make sure you are including correct header ...

Comment: I also encountered this problem. How did you guys solve it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit release to TDM-GCC 4.9.2 32-bit release

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).